# Can a really simple example be created

Tags: cryptography

The problem with padlock analogies (which are wonderful) comes when the lock parts are related to public and private keys. The transition is usually opaque, rendering the padlock analogy not useful.
   I would like to find an example of a simple message, say five characters, with a simple public key, based on a one or two digit number, and a detailed example of how use the public key to encrypt the message. Then use the private key in a detailed way to unencrypt the message. For example, a public key of 2 and a private key of 5 which are factors of 10. Can this be done with simple arithmetic?

Comment: i've seen you tube videos like that, both the color mixing and simple modulus-based PKs

Comment: Have you checked the [example from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Example)?

Comment: Yes. Computerphile (or Numberphile, tbh, cba) on youtube did that a while ago, using unpadded RSA for simplification reasons.